# Django objects.filter not consistent in dealing with unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

Normally a filter like this would give back the correct result:

```
Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__startswith='Beatle')
```

But from time to time it does not! And I have to make it unicode to work:

```
Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__startswith=u'Beatle')
```

Does that mean we always have to put unicode strings there or is this a bug? Any thoughts?
Thanks,
Sep

Comment: It depends. Show us an example of your data and how query behaves, plus the database info and it's encoding/collation settings. Generally, if the string has unicode characters, then of course you'll need to use unicode.

Comment: Like @DmitryShevchenko suggested, what db back-end are you using? Usually this should not happen but it might be an encoding issue.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this situation but so far things work.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry and Miki, I'm trying to recreate this situation but so far things work and no need to put the u''. I'm using MySQL 5.5 on windows. Python 2.7. Django 1.4.1
The original data that was entered to Django through Python shell was Ascii.
My encoding is default locale on Windows which is probably Latin-1

Comment: What was happening before:
1:M relationship from Blog to Entry

    >>>bbb = Blog.objects.get(id=3)
>>>bbb.name
u'Beatles Blog'

>>>Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__endswith='Blog')
[<Blog: Beatles Blog>]

>>>Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__startswith='Beatles')
[]

>>>Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__startswith=u'Beatles')
[<Blog: Beatles Blog>]

Comment: Is there a possibility the inconsistent results appeared while in an *ipython* session?

Comment: It appeared when I was in Python shell running Django manage.py

Comment: And I am asking you again, was this python shell `ipython`?. Because if you have it installed `manage.py` will use it as a shell. Also, ipython had a known problem with unicode support and the problems were similar to what you described. I don't know if they have fix it by now.

Comment: I see. It was not iPython. Once it happens again, I will keep the whole log.